# WP Cli + xargs fails

Tags: media, wp-cli

I'm trying to regenerate thumbnails using `seq` but I get `signal 9` error.
here is my command:

```
$ seq 146280 146300 | xargs wp media regenerate --url='http://www.my-site.com'
Found 15 images to regenerate.
1/15 Regenerated thumbnails for "X" (ID 146300).
2/15 Regenerated thumbnails for "X" (ID 146298).
3/15 Regenerated thumbnails for "X" (ID 146297).
4/15 Regenerated thumbnails for "X" (ID 146296).
5/15 Regenerated thumbnails for "X" (ID 146295).
6/15 Regenerated thumbnails for "X" (ID 146294).
xargs: wp: terminated by signal 9
```

When I execute `wp media regenerate 146292` it works just fine so I don't know whats going on.

How can I see the error log and debug it?

Comment: I suspect this is not an issue with WP-CLI but your process being killed by the system.

Comment: but its a specific ID thats getting killed

Comment: Is this image particularly big? You might run out of RAM when resizing.

Comment: That's a good option, since when I run this specific image it via wp-cli its just fine. Thanks!